# direct access to to gitlab database

Tags: gitlab

I am running the AWS AMI from gitlab. I am trying to access the postgres database directly using psql. I thought I could just use the credentials in database.yml, since the rails application is working fine:

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -U gitlab -d gitlabhq_production
```

But I get:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "gitlab"
```

How can the rails app be connecting to the database while psql cannot?

Comment: @Daniel Alder's comment pointed my in the right direction:    

    `ubuntu@gitlab:~$ sudo -u gitlab-psql /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/ gitlabhq_production
    psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
     Is the server running locally and accepting
     connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql//.s.PGSQL.5432"?
    ubuntu@gitlab:~$ sudo -u gitlab-psql /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql gitlabhq_production
    psql (9.2.9)
    Type "help" for help.
    
    gitlabhq_production=#`

Comment: Please note [GitLab's `Use at your own risk` warning](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/troubleshooting/postgresql.html) for any such direct DB access.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
sudo -u gitlab-psql /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/ gitlabhq_production
```

Comment: This answer is closest to what ended up working for me. I had to leave off the `-h  /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/` though, as that caused an error: `psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory`, even though that dir does exist and is the `gitlab-psql` user's home dir.

Comment: Please note [GitLab's `Use at your own risk` warning](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/troubleshooting/postgresql.html) for any such direct DB access.

Comment: @KatrinLeinweber good point. but I think if you come to the point where you search for how you can access the database, it doesn't matter anymore..

Answer (score 13):

googled and found an [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/513) about this.

so, just type `sudo gitlab-rails dbconsole` :D

Comment: Not really solving the problem because this does not give you a superuser database access.

Comment: It worked for me, my Gitlab was installed by apt source

Answer (score 0):

But this one does give you full access:

```
sudo -u gitlab-psql psql template1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -u gitlab-psql /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql -d gitlabhq_production
```

Comment: remarkably close to my answer. and the `-d` doesn't really make a difference

Answer (score 0):

su - git
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -U gitlab -d gitlabhq_production -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql

works for me with gitlab-ce and the embedded postgres. Optional for better interactive working start a bash as git. 
The (unix)-user git seems to be a peer to the postgresuser gitlab, authenticates without a password (/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf).